# How do I add a one-to-one relationship in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql, database, model

```
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| pid   | varchar(99) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)


+-------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| pid   | varchar(2000) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| recid | varchar(2000) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is my table.  pid is just the id of the user.  "recid" is a recommended song for that user.

I hope to have a list of pid's, and then recommended songs for each person. 
Of course, in my 2nd table, (pid, recid) would be unique key.

How do I do a one-to-one query for this ?

Comment: One-to-One relationships should be modeled to exist in the same table, not split between two (or more).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# retrieve all songs associated to a given user    
SELECT songs.*
FROM user
INNER JOIN songs ON (user.pid = songs.pid)
WHERE user.pid = ?
```

Answer (score 0):

You may create FKs with query like

```
ALTER TABLE `foo`
ADD FOREIGN KEY (`bar_id`) REFERENCES `bar` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

and see the [mysql documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).
Also note that Mysql only supports foreign keys in InnoDB engine.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a join (inner) to get the information out.  Here is a refrence that I've  used and have found helpful.
[Joins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL))